# Vectors of std::shared_ptr Lose Data

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr, delete-operator

I am attempting to build `std::vectors` and `std::maps` of `std::shared_ptrs`, but they seem to have a habit of losing data. By that, I mean that when I push `std::shared_ptrs` into them, some of them will delete the data they point to.

Specifically, the first `std::shared_ptr` to be pushed into a `std::vector` is deleted. This is confusing as pushing a `std::shared_ptr` into a `std::vector` should increment the reference count until the original `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope, correct? It seems that no other `std::shared_ptrs` are deleted, but I cannot check until I get this issue resolved, as it checks the values by iterating.

I apologize if I have not explained myself well enough. I am still adjusting to this site.

EDIT: [Here](http://pastebin.com/pDVgw3tK) is the code for the two relevant classes. The problem should lie in the Load member functions. It is quite large, since it's a file parser, so I can't tell where the problem is at. Value is a member variable that is a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<NBT::Tag::Base>>` for List and a `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<NBT::Tag::Base>>` for Compound.

Comment: Could you possibly post a code sample? I tried to imitate what you've described with boost::shared_ptr and it seems to behave correctly.

Comment: Can you post some code?  Its difficult to see what might be wrong without seeing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll post it now. There are 10 classes and one base class, but I'll just post the classes that are relevant.

Comment: I think just posting the few lines of code that declare your shared_ptr and insert it into the vector would be sufficient.  Try to make it as simple as possible while still illustrating the problem for us-- it will help us help you.

Comment: The missing towel operator on line 42 results in undefined behavior, causing your pointers to delete themselves.

Comment: @OniLink Have you tried to narrow your problem down at all?  I have a feeling that if you tried to reproduce your problem with only 5 lines of code you would find the error pretty quickly (and its probably unrelated to inserting shared_ptrs into vectors).

Comment: @JaredC Believe me, I have been trying everything to solve it. I'm going to go over it once more and try something, but I highly doubt it will work.

Comment: What is the error you're getting (if any)? Is the code resulting in a segmentation fault/access violation when you try to use the `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @Toolbox, yeah, there is a segfault.

Comment: @OniLink run your program through [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) to locate the source of the segfault.

Comment: @Sam Miller Woah, the entire problem has been shifted elsewhere, to a vector of bytes.

Comment: Nevermind, I have never used valgrind before so I wasn't used to the output. Anyways, I got it working now, thanks to Valgrind. Thank you, Sam Miller!

Comment: @OniLink I've turned my comment into an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your program through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to locate the source of the segfault.

Comment: "Use valgrind" is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just construct shared_ptr's willy-nilly, they need to be constructed from each other, else they think they're the only owning shared_ptr and delete the object when they go out of scope. If you want to be able to construct shared_ptr's directly from an object, you need to inherit from `enable_shared_from_this<Type>`. I can't read your code easily (there's a lot there), but your symptoms sound to me like you've been misconstructing them.

Comment: So creating a std::shared_ptr from a new statement won't work? Because I construct the first shared_ptr from a new statement, and the rest are copied from that shared_ptr.

Comment: Alright, I have done some debugging and found that no, it does not seem to be a problem of std::shared_ptrs thinking they are the only owner. I used use_count at various locations where it could be deleted (usually right when a shared_ptr is about to go out of scope), and it always gave more than 1 owner, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @OniLink: How strange, that was pretty much the only idea I had.